# Do/Return behave differently in Compile -- why?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am wondering if this is a bug or a documented behaviour?

```
f1 = Function[v, 
  Do[If[v[[i]] < 0, Return[v[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[v]}]]

c1 = Compile[{{v, _Integer, 1}}, 
  Do[If[v[[i]] < 0, Return[v[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[v]}]]
```

When applying them to a list containing no negative numbers, we get different results:

```
In[66]:= Through[{f1, c1}[{1, 2, 3}]]

Out[66]= {Null, 3}
```

This has caused a bug when I tried to compile a [short function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176518/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-period-of-a-repeating-list-in-mathematica/8178091#8178091) (actually a modified version of it).

`Do` alone doesn't show the problem:

```
c2 = Compile[{}, Do[i, {i, 5}]]

c2[] (* returns nothing, as expected *)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the answers by @Pillsy and @Leonid, the issue is that the original function sometimes returns `Null` and sometimes an integer.  In contrast, the compiled function always returns an integer.  In V8, we can see this using `CompilePrint`:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint @
  Compile[{{v,_Integer,1}},Do[If[v[[i]]<0,Return[v[[i]]]],{i,1,Length[v]}]]
```

which, under V8.0.4, produces this result:

```
        1 argument
        1 Boolean register
        6 Integer registers
        1 Tensor register
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        T(I1)0 = A1
        I3 = 0
        I0 = 1
        Result = I5

1   I2 = Length[ T(I1)0]
2   I4 = I3
3   goto 10
4   I5 = Part[ T(I1)0, I4]
5   B0 = I5 < I3
6   if[ !B0] goto 10
7   I5 = Part[ T(I1)0, I4]
8   goto 11
9   goto 10
10  if[ ++ I4 < I2] goto 4
11  goto 12
12  Return
```

We can see that the result of the compiled function is whatever ends up in integer register `I5`.  Following the flow of the decompiled instructions, we see that if there is no match then `I5` will end up containing the last element of the list.

The behaviour of the compiler might change between releases of Mathematica.  I think that it is reasonable to argue that the compiler should issue at least a warning in circumstances where the return result type is ambiguous.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I also looked at, to see what is returned.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say this a bug with the way `Compile` is working, but it's not terribly surprising that it isn't working right.  `Compile` does make pretty specific assumptions about not only its inputs (here, that `v` will be a list of integers) but also its outputs. Compiled functions are supposed to return values that of a single, specific  type, and that type must be one of the types that's acceptable as an input for a compiled function: `True|False`, `Integer`, et c., and arrays of the same. It would obviously be better if the function complained with a message and then returned `Null`, but in order to be a well-behaved function for compilation, you need to provide an appropriate integer return value as a defalult.

**EDIT** to clarify about output types, per [Szabolcs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695132/szabolcs)' comment below.

Comment: Not return values of the same type as the input, but return the same type of value regardless of the specific input (i.e. can't return both Null and an Integer).  Yes, what you say is reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

I would not say this is a bug. As @Pillsy noted, `Compile`-d function is more restricted since it has to always return the same type. Since `Do` is a scoping construct, the `Return` inside `Do` only breaks out of `Do`, not `Function`. Therefore, in some cases it returns a vector element, in others it returns `Null`. Strictly speaking, as written, the function should not compile at all. However, one can be more flexible and assume that the writer of the function knows better, and will discard the answer in that particular case. With this interpretation, `Compile` is free to produce any answer in that case. What it does here is to produce the last element in the list. And I think, this is no more ad-hoc than producing a fixed number every time. I also think that such corner cases can not be avoided when a much more flexible symbolic code is compiled. `Compile` could have had more strict rules in this case and *require* some meaningful return (of the same type) in all cases, but it is not clear to me whether this would really be beneficial. In a sense, all C is like that - the compiler assumes that you know what you are doing, but allows you to create a lot of undefined behavior if you are not careful.

Answer (score 3):

Some additional information you might find useful. Consider this:

```
In[26]:= f1 = 
 Function[v, Do[If[v[[i]] < 0, Return[v[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[v]}]; 
  last = 1;];

In[27]:= last

Out[27]= last

In[28]:= f1[{-1, 2, 3}]

In[29]:= last

Out[29]= 1
```

Eventhough the the function should have returned on the first element it got to last=1, Hence, as other have noted, Return is broken. This will not be fixed since there is too much code that depends on this behavior.

Now, your can use:

```
In[30]:= f2 = Function[v, Module[{},
   Do[If[v[[i]] < 0, Return[v[[i]], Module]], {i, 1, Length[v]}]; 
   last2 = 1;]];

In[31]:= f2[{-1, 2, 3}]

Out[31]= -1

In[32]:= last2

Out[32]= last2
```

Which behaves as expected. Unfortunately, however,

```
In[33]:= c1 = Compile[{{v, _Integer, 1}},
  Module[{},
   Do[If[v[[i]] < 0, Return[v[[i]], Module]], {i, 1, Length[v]}];
   ]
  ];
```

will not compile.

Here is a way to make that work.

```
In[137]:= c1=Compile[{{v,_Integer,1}},
Module[{res=1},
Do[If[v[[i]]<0,res=v[[i]];Break[]],{i,1,Length[v]}];
If[res==1,Internal`CompileError[]];
res
]
,"RuntimeOptions"->{"RuntimeErrorHandler"->Function[Null]}]

In[140]:= c1[{1,2,3,1}]

In[141]:= c1[{1,2,3,-1}]

Out[141]= -1
```

Check the output.

```
In[139]:= CompilePrint[c1]
```

Some further notes: "RuntimeErrorHandler"->Function[Null] this is a Function! Think about that for a second. You can Thow, Message anything!

So something like this works.

```
cfquietfail = 
  Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Exp[x], 
   "RuntimeOptions" -> {"WarningMessages" -> False, 
     "RuntimeErrorHandler" -> 
      Function[Message[MyFunctionName::"I can complain here!"]; 
       Throw[$Failed]]}];
Catch[ cfquietfail[{1000.}]]
```

I hope this is useful.